# Problemas com Where

Tags: sql, select, data, cast, where

Estou usando MariaDB e tenho um problema na cláusula `WHERE` do banco.

A query está dentro do Excel que me traz períodos do banco através do filtro mês.
Porém me pediram para alterar para um período de tempo, só que está me trazendo uma tabela vazia e não consigo entender o porquê.

```
FROM
perfilacoes_table
WHERE
fila_atendimento regexp "DENTALUNIGRC" and
month( date_format(STR_TO_DATE(perfilacoes_table.data_inicio_chamada, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') ) > month( DATE_ADD(date_format(curdate(), '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL -1 DAY) ) -1 and
month( date_format(STR_TO_DATE(perfilacoes_table.data_inicio_chamada, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') ) <= month( DATE_ADD(date_format(curdate(), '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL -1 DAY) ) and
date_format(STR_TO_DATE(perfilacoes_table.data_inicio_chamada, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') < DATE_ADD(date_format(curdate(), '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL 0 DAY)
ORDER BY
date_format(STR_TO_DATE(data_inicio_chamada, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y/%m/%d') desc;
```

Esta versão me traz informações, mas preciso mudar ela então alterei para:

```
FROM
perfilacoes_table
WHERE
fila_atendimento regexp "DENTALUNIGRC" and
perfilacoes_table.data_inicio_chamada BETWEEN CAST('2018-12-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2018-12-31' AS DATE)
ORDER BY
date_format(STR_TO_DATE(data_inicio_chamada, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y/%m/%d') desc;
```

Porém me traz uma tabela vazia.

Existem outras querys que fiz o mesmo procedimento e funcionou corretamente.

Estou sem entender porque em uma traz valores e em outra não.

Comment: Lembrando que no caso que traz resultados estou rodando a mesma agora durante o mês de dezembro, ou seja, está me retornando os dados referentes à Dezembro. Da mesma forma que estou usando o BETWEEN datas de dezembro.